# new to kamailio need to develop a software phone using kamailio and open sip windows

Tags: voip, kamailio, opensips, windows-phone-voip, openser

I am new to Kamailio. i have already read the details of the package. But a documentation was given for ubuntu but i need to develop for windows. I need to develop a soft phone using that. Can anyone guide me how to start with kamailio and open sip in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Kamailio can run only on Linux/Unix/MacOS systems, maybe one can get it working on Windows, but it would require substantial work of C development.

If you are working in Windows, I recommend to run Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, ...) in a virtual machine or container.

For example, VirtualBox is free and you can install it on Windows, then deploy a virtual machine with Linux on it. You can have the virtual machine with an IP in the local network by choosing bridged network interface, so it appears as another computer in the LAN. Then you can have a SIP app from Windows connecting to the Kamailio in the VirtualBox.

Similar, but with a container, you can use Docker to run Linux on Windows. If you search on the web, you will find some Docker files for running Kamailio.